# Is it possible to draw pyqt widget by other dlls?

Tags: video-streaming, pyqt

I need create a program which can show web cameras (hikvision IR ip66),
they provide me with ocx and dll, and some API documents.

one API function is like this(in windows):

```
bool playVideo( HWND handle, ...)
```

and my code is like this:

```
widget = QWidget()
wid = widget.winId()
dll.playVideo(int(wid))
```

and failed. I don't know what is wrong, any ideas? or other better way to do this job in pyqt? (for example, use phonon?)

Answer (score 0):

When creating the QWidget you need to pass the attribute:

> Qt::WA_NativeWindows

```
QWidget(parent, Qt.WindowFlags(Qt.WA_NativeWindows))
```

Keep in mind that this will make all the parent widgets also Native unless you specify:

> Qt::WA_DontCreateNativeAncestors

Comment: after make this, How could I let native dll draw things on the widget?